# Call async flutter function in Android can't get return value

Tags: android, flutter, dart

I'm trying to leverage `MethodChannel` to call dart function from Kotlin in Android. When using `await` in flutter's function, the Android side can't obtain the return value. Here is my code:

Flutter:

```
import 'dart:async';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: const MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyHomePage({super.key, required this.title});

  final String title;

  @override
  State<MyHomePage> createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return const Center();
  }

  static const platform = MethodChannel('myChannel');

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    platform.setMethodCallHandler(myFunction);
  }

  Future<String> myFunction(MethodCall call) async {
    switch (call.method) {
      case "yourMethod":
        await Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 5));
        return "delayed 5 seconds";
    }
    return "not implemented";
  }
}
```

Kotlin:

```
class MainActivity: FlutterActivity() {

    override fun configureFlutterEngine(flutterEngine: FlutterEngine) {
        GeneratedPluginRegistrant.registerWith(flutterEngine);
    }

    class MyBook: BookApi {
        override fun search(keyword: String): List<Book?> {
            return listOf(Book("book_title1", "author1"))
        }

    }

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        val flutterEngine = FlutterEngine(this)

        flutterEngine
            .dartExecutor
            .executeDartEntrypoint(
                DartExecutor.DartEntrypoint.createDefault()
            )

        val channel = MethodChannel(flutterEngine.dartExecutor.binaryMessenger, "myChannel")
        
        channel.invokeMethod("yourMethod", "yourArguments", object: MethodChannel.Result {
            override fun success(result: Any?) {
                Log.d(TAG, "result = $result")
            }

            override fun error(errorCode: String, errorMessage: String?, errorDetails: Any?) {
                Log.d(
                    TAG,
                    "errorCode = $errorCode, errorMessage = $errorMessage, errorDetails = $errorDetails"
                )
            }

            override fun notImplemented() {
                Log.d(TAG, "notImplemented")
            }
        })
    }

    companion object {
        private const val TAG = "MainActivity"
    }
}
```

According to my research, the function returned value should be passed through callback in `MethodChannel.Result`, but it never called.

If I remove the line `await Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 5));`, everything is ok, the returned value passed from the `success` callback.

Is it supposed to prevent `await` in `MethodCallHandler`? If true, how do I achieve this function?

Answer (score 0):

The Future.delayed method in Flutter's MethodChannel creates a future that completes after a specified duration, by using the Future.delayed function you're delaying the execution of the next line of code which could be returning the result to the native code. This means that the result won't be returned until after the specified duration has passed.

This behavior can prevent the function from returning a value to Android native code because the future isn't complete until after the delay, and the MethodChannel expects the function to return a result immediately.

It's generally recommended to avoid using Future.delayed in MethodChannel functions, as it can result in unexpected behavior. Instead, consider using a different approach, such as returning a Future that completes immediately and using the then method to perform any necessary operations after the result has been returned to the native code.

Comment: The Future.delayed is only used for simulating async action, do you mean I can't have any async action such as making http request and passing the value through method channel?

Comment: @NamekMaster yeah, consider using a different approach, such as returning a Future that completes immediately and using the then method to perform any necessary operations after the result has been returned to the native code.

Comment: That's not true, I finally fixed this. The reason is Fragment's onCreate called before flutter widget's initState function, so just wait until widget appear on screen then invokeMethod. Anyway, thanks for your help.